# ImageMagickで、画像に、よい感じの右矢印を描画したい

Tags: imagemagick

やりたいこと
画像の左上(x120 y50)によい感じの右矢印を描画したい

試したこと

```
convert input.jpg \
-fill none -stroke red -strokewidth 2 \
-draw "path 'M 100,100 L 200,100 L 180,90 M 200,100 L 180,110'" \
output.jpg
```

まずは、上記矢印の、直線を半分ぐらいにしてy位置を上へ移動しようと思い下記を試したのですが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
convert input.jpg \
-fill none -stroke red -strokewidth 2 \
-draw "path 'M 100,50 L 200,50 L 180,90 M 200,50 L 180,110'" \
output.jpg
```

直線のy位置は上へ移動したのですが、矢印部分がうまくいきません。

Q1.ImageMagickで、画像に、よい感じの右矢印を描画するにはどうすればよいですか？
・「-draw "path"」を使用するのですか？
・「矢印を描画するには、-arrowオプションを使用する必要がある」のかと思い、「-arrow 5%」を追記してみたのですが、矢印は描画されませんでした。
・「-draw "polygon"」も試してみたのですが、矢印は描画されませんでした。

Q2.pathについて
・このpathは、SVGのpathと同じですか？
・pathをGUIかなにかで手軽に確認あるいは編集する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1.ImageMagickで、画像に、よい感じの右矢印を描画するにはどうすればよいですか？

`translate` で `x=120 y=50` の座標を原点にしておくと少しは判りやすいでしょう。(以下の例では矢印の先端位置を「原点」としています)

```bash
convert -size 400x200 xc:white \
-fill none -stroke red -strokewidth 2 \
-draw "translate 120 50;path 'M -50,0 L 0,0 L -20,-10 M 0,0 L -20,10'" \
output.jpg
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> Q2.pathについて
> ・このpathは、SVGのpathと同じですか？

はい。[SVG Path Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataGeneralInformation)

Comment: 「translate で x=120 y=50 の座標を原点にしておくと少しは判りやすい」translateは単なる移動だと思っていたのですが、その後の座標が原点になるのですね。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

矢印の画像を別で用意して元の画像に合成する方が簡単かと思います。

Comment: ちょっと凝った矢印を描画する場合は、こちらの案を検討したいと思います。